# Socket io multiplayer game infrastructure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

```
var connectionHandler = function(socket) {
var player = null;

socket.on('login', function(data) {
    player = {
        data: okeyServer.playerJoin(data),
        socket: socket
             };
    socket.emit('welcome');
});

socket.on('info server', function(data) {
    var info = okeyServer.Info();
    socket.emit('info server', info);
});

socket.on('join game', function (data) {
    var gameid = data.gameid;
    var side = data.side;
    okeyServer.playerJoinGame(player, gameid, side);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    okeyServer.playerLeave(player);
    io.sockets.emit('player leave', player);
});
}
```

I am trying to do a multiplayer game app with socket.io. When player connects, i want a 'login' message to be sent first. and i initialize the player variable for further use.
Other messages uses the player variable later.

How can i make sure client sent a 'login' message before making other requests. 
I can check if player is null on every request where i need player but that seems ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install the other listeners from within the `login` listener:

```
var connectionHandler = function(socket) {
  var player = null;

  socket.on('login', function(data) {
    // If we already have a player, just return a `welcome` message.
    if (player !== null) {
      return socket.emit('welcome');
    }

    // Store player.
    player = {
      data: okeyServer.playerJoin(data),
      socket: socket
    };

    // Emit welcome message.
    socket.emit('welcome');

    // Set up the rest of the listeners.
    socket.on('info server', function(data) {
      var info = okeyServer.Info();
      socket.emit('info server', info);
    });

    socket.on('join game', function (data) {
      var gameid = data.gameid;
      var side = data.side;
      okeyServer.playerJoinGame(player, gameid, side);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      okeyServer.playerLeave(player);
      io.sockets.emit('player leave', player);
    });
  });
};
```

This assumes that a `login` message is only ever emitted once by the client during the lifetime of the connection. If that's not the case, you need to make some changes.